# In Python why do list slices behave like parts of lists sometimes, and behave like copies of lists another times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variable-assignment, slice

In the first example a slice of a list behaves like a part of a list:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l[0:2] = []
>>> l
[3]
```

In the second example a slice of a list behaves like a copy of a list

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> k = l[0:2]
>>> k = []
>>> l[1, 2, 3]
```

Which general rule makes this difference?
(I guess it is related to the semantics of assignment somehow. In the first example `l[0:2]` refers to a slice of `l`, but in the second example `k` refers only to a copy of a slice of l. In the second example does `l[0:2]` refer to a copy or a part?)

Comment: Slice assignment != slicing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I undersand it now.